# java .contains() test whether string contains + sign

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
Scanner input3 = new Scanner(new File("internal"));
Scanner input4 = new Scanner(new File("internal"));
for (int i = 0; i < narray[ctr]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < marray[ctr]; j++) {
        try{
            String test4 = input4.nextLine();
            System.out.println("test4:" + test4);
            if(test4.contains("+")){
                a[i][j] = input3.useDelimiter(" ").next()
                                                  .replaceAll(",", " ")
                                                  .replace("+", "")
                                                  .replace("~", "")
                                                  .replace("^", "")
                                                  .replace("v", "")
                                                  .replace(">", "")
                                                  .replace(".", "")
                                                  .replace("A", "");
                System.out.println("hello1");
            } 
            else {
                a[i][j] = input3.useDelimiter(" ").next()
                                                  .replaceAll(",", " ")
                                                  .replace("+", "")
                                                  .replace("~", "")
                                                  .replace("^", "")
                                                  .replace("v", "")
                                                  .replace(">", "")
                                                  .replace(".", "");
                System.out.println("hello2");
            }

            p3.println(a[i][j]);
        }
        catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the following inputfile 'internal':

```
  A A + +
A,x,x,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A|
 , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , |
```

The program gives me the output:

```
VVVVV
 x x                              
V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V
```

instead of:

```
VVVVV
A x x A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V
```

Why is the program not only replacing 'A' on the first line which contains '+'? How can I change it so that it not replaces the 'A' on the second line without '+'?

Comment: Not that it solves anything but your `replace("+", "").replace("~", "").replace("^", "").replace("v", "").replace(">", "").replace(".", "").replace("A", "");` is the same as `replaceAll("[+~^v>.A]","");`

Comment: narray is the number of lines of the file: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only checks for + in the line it is currently scanning. The line with all the As has no + so the As get replaced...

Comment: Thanks. I changed .next() to .nextLine() which works